# ¿Como pasar los id uno por uno de un arreglo json a un metodo?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Hola amigos me encuentro con un problema espero me puedan ayudar de antemano se los agradezco mucho.

De mi arreglo de objetos Json he podido obtener todos los id como se muestra en el siguiente código.

```
for(var x in valores){                  
               resultado = valores[x]['id_Persona'];                       
               alert(resultado);
           }
```

En mi método necesito pasar este id como parámetro.

```
 var id_Persona = resultado;


    if (id_Persona != 0) {            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "frmPersonas.aspx/Obtener_Personas",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{id_persona:"' + id_Persona + '"}',  // Aqui es donde quiero pasarle los id uno por uno los cuales los obtuve arriba.
```

Alguien sabe como se le puede hacer para pasar estos id uno por uno. Cabe resaltar que no tengo error ninguno. Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano se los agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
valores = [1,2,3,4,5, 'ultimo'];
for(i=0; i<valores.length; i++){
recibeParamatro(valores[i]);
}
function recibeParamatro(parametro){
  //recibo el parametro
 alert(parametro);
}//end function recibeParamatro
```

Si te fijas mi creo un ciclo for para recorrer uno a uno el arreglo, en este llamo a mi funcion y mando un parametro le cual lo recibo y hare lo que deseo